# Create git repo out of preexisting website on server

Tags: git, magento, version-control, repository, staging

I'm supposed to start implementing source control via git for a preexisting Magento site hosted by MediaTemple, who actually already have git installed, so installation on the server isn't even an obstacle. However, the website and all its files already exist live on the server, as well as a separate staging environment.

MediaTemple provides basic instructions for git usage on their servers: https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1594/Using+Git#gs

But I'm still a bit fuzzy. Git repos must begin bare, correct? You can't just appoint a ready-made/populated unversioned website as a repository.

In that case, should I create a repo on the server and simply move or copy all the files from the staging site into it? The site should still connect to the database then, since that should be configured within the site files.

Then I'd clone that on my localhost, for development, then push to the staging environment and provided all is well I just sync the staging site files to the live production site.

Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn any existing unversioned folder of files into a git repository. Just `git init` start adding your files and creating commits, and then `git remote add origin user@gitserver:pathTo/repo.git` where pathTo/repo.git is a bare repo on your git server.